# Spring, bath auth: Authorized by same login

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have app with bath auth authorization and sessions. I have users with same logins, but with different types(like `USER`, `ADMIN`, `OPERATOR` - the username is unique ***along with its type***, i.e. there can be 2 users John (one with the type `USER`, the other with the type `ADMIN`). But there cannot be 2 users John  with type `USER`. And for each type there is a separate domain where the front is located.

How can i do such authorization? 
Spring service `UserDetails` has method `loadUserByUsername(String login)`, and i need use url from request or something to find user that i need.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to setup custom authorization.

The Spring Security reference docs (https://spring.io/projects/spring-security#learn) address how to setup custom authorization.

Also, https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider provides guidance there.

Spring Security is wonderful in it's ability to implement custom classes of it's interfaces for particular use cases.  The tricky part is finding the appropriate interface to implement a custom version for and that takes a little digging to discover.

Comment: it hasn't `HttpServletRequest` in methods to know domains of front, from where i get current request